# Sort ArrayList from file

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a file containing a list of colors & their hexadecimal value (Navy #000080). I am able to read the file contents into an arrayList, however, I am trying to sort this list based on the hexadecimal value. As such I created two additional classes, one which contains the method used to compare the hexadecimal values and one called Color which represents the type of information I am storing in my list. My problem is that when I try to add the file contents to the List as follows:-

```
colorNames.add(inputFileName.nextLine());
```

I get an error message "The method add(Color) in the type List is not applicable for the arguments (String)"

which is because I created my list as follows:-

```
List<Color> colorNames = new ArrayList<Color>();
```

I understand what the error means but I don't know how to resolve it or if the approach am taking is the right one! Any suggestions would be appreciated. Below is my source.

```
//import statements

public class ReadStoreShow {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Please input a filename: ");
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(System.in);
    String fileName = inputFile.nextLine();
    File colors = new File(fileName.toString());

    //Receive number N from user
    System.out.println("Please input a number N: ");
    Scanner inputNumber = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number = inputNumber.nextInt();

    List<Color> colorNames = new ArrayList<Color>();

    try {
        Scanner inputFileName = new Scanner(colors);
        while (inputFileName.hasNext()) {
            colorNames.add(inputFileName.nextLine());
        }
        List<Color> subListOfColors = colorNames.subList(0, number);
        Collections.sort(subListOfColors, new ColorComp());
        for (int i = 0; i<subListOfColors.size(); i++)
            System.out.println(subListOfColors.get(i));
        inputFileName.close();

    } 

    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found");
        System.out.println("Please ensure that file name is <<name>>.txt");

    }

}

}
class ColorComp implements Comparator<Color>{
    @Override
    public int compare(Color c1, Color c2){
        String string1 = c1.toString();
        String string2 = c2.toString();
        int compareResult = string1.compareTo(string2);
        if(compareResult < 0) {return 1;}
        else {return -1;}
    }
}
class Color {
    private String colorName;
    private String colorHex;

    public Color(String n, String h) {
        this.colorName = n;
        this.colorHex = h;
    }
    public String getColorHex() {return colorHex;}
    public String getColorName() {return colorName;}
    public String toString() {return "Color Name: " + this.colorName + "Color Hex: " + this.colorHex;}
}
```

Comment: You have a `Color` constructor that takes a name and an hex value as parameter. Just split correctly the `String` you got from `nextLine()`, create a new `Color` and add it to the list. And IMO `colorHex` should be an `int` not a `String`.

Comment: thanks @ZouZou, how do I split the input? Regex?

Comment: Off-topic comment: don't create new Scanner each time you want to read data from console. Create one scanner like `Scanner keybord = new Scanner(System.in);` and use it each time you want to read data from user.

Comment: @user76020 `String#split` will do it fine.

Comment: could you give me an example plz

Comment: @user76020 Did you read the javadoc of split? There is an example.

Comment: Yeah I have, found a solution....thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think first you read data from file and store into Color class object and after that you have add that object to array.